# Icon for "Services"

Tags: icon, interface-design

I'm making a web-site for a friend of mine. She works mainly with nail-art and make ups (I don't really know).

Anyway, I wonder what would be good for an icon for "Services" of this kind of thing? I have some ideas, but I'm not so sure about them. I would like to hear what you guys think could be the icon for this.

I tried these so far:

1. Three nails with different colors that go in an arc shape.
2. A women silhouette
3. I know that probably the icon should contain some brushes (like tools) for nails/make-up etc, but due the small pixel number of the icon the idea of this become very unclear. And if I'll paint only varnish with a brush it may consider as something very restricted (limited) for one service or something. I don't like this.

The size of the icon is small (30x30), so there is not opportunity for detail.

Comment: When I get stuck for ideas for an icon, I often do a search on [the nounproject](https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=nail%20paint).  I have no affiliation with that website.  To be fair you might not find an exact match there, but you could potentially alter an existing design or create one from scratch using ideas you've seen.

Answer (score 1):

It's really hard to say due to the nature of the size of the icon. 30x30 is extremely small and as you have said, very little room to be able to add in any detail.

You want to keep it as simple as possible, so that the icon gets the message across as to what the website is actually about. So, you wouldn't use a paint brush as you're doing make up and so on and so fourth.

If I were designing this, I'd keep it as simple as possible and maybe even keep it one colour as if the image has a few colours then this could lack quality.

Here is an idea as to what you can do - 
http://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/nail-polish_100163#term=nail&page=1&position=26

This one get the point across that it is in a matter of fact for nails.

You can also try searching that site for inspiration. They're all really good for icons!

Try and create your own.

Let me know how you get on!